# Formatting date in a repeat control?

Tags: xpages

I have some code that displays a line in a repeat control.

```
return "<tr><td>" +  rowData.getColumnValues()[1] + "</td><td>" + rowData.getColumnValues()[2] +  "</td><td>" +  rowData.getColumnValues()[3]+ "</td></tr>"
```

rowData.getColumnValues()[1]  is a date value.  In the view, it is only displaying the date, which I want.   I would expect the same behavior in  my repeat control but that is not what is happening.  It is dipaying both data and time in the repeat control.  Is there an easy way to just get it tos display the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method **getDateOnly()** for getting just the date part of class lotus.domino.local.DateTime (NotesDateTime)

```
return "<tr><td>" +  rowData.getColumnValues()[1].getDateOnly() + ...
```

If values can be empty then use getDateOnly() only if current value is a date value:

```
return "<tr><td>" +  (typeof rowData.getColumnValues()[1] === "lotus.domino.local.DateTime" ? rowData.getColumnValues()[1].getDateOnly() : rowData.getColumnValues()[1]) +  ...
```

Comment: rowData.getColumnValues()[1] returns a string not a Date object, so an error occurs since getDateOnly() is not a method within String.

Comment: You wrote in your question "rowData.getColumnValues()[1] is a date value" - for this works **getDateOnly()**

Comment: Is your second column already converted to a text with e.g. @Text in view column formula? I tested with `@Created` for column value and it worked well.

Comment: I just realized my first value was blank.  When I added a value for that field, this answer works fine.  But I am going to have to use typeof before using DateOnly.

Comment: I see. I added a `typeof` version which can handle empty values.

Comment: I added to your answer with the following: var val = rowData.getColumnValues()[1]; var dt = typeof(val) === "lotus.domino.local.DateTime" ? val.getDateOnly() : "";  This solves the problem if a particular value happens to be non DateTime.

Comment: You beat me to it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Date value is formatted normally, I would just split the string on the space character and use the substring from the array.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var dateSplit = rowData.getColumnValues()[1].split(" ");
return "<tr><td>" +  dateSplit[0] + "</td><td>" + rowData.getColumnValues()[2] +  "</td><td>" +  rowData.getColumnValues()[3]+ "</td></tr>"
```